# Typescript: is not assignable to type error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-cli

I am new to using typescript with angular 2. I am using version 1 of angular 2-cli. When compiling, I get this error saying "is not assignable to type Assignment[]". I looked at the data types and it looks okay so far, but I am not sure what the error is exactly. Thanks for your help.

**Here is a photo of the error from the console.**
[image]

**data.ts file - these are two of the items that appear in the array**

```
export const Assignments: Assignment[] = [
  {
    "a_type": "one",
    "a_title": "Assignment 1",
    "symbol": 1,
    "show": false,
    "tooltip": {
        "left": 82
    },
    "buttonPos":{
        "left": 130
    },
    "printTop": 0,
    "instructions": "Instructions here",
    "due_date": "sept-15.png",
    "percentage": "10.png",
    "taskA": {
        "name": "Option A",
        "a_title": "Task A",
        "information": "Instructions for task A",
        "selectA": true
    }
}, {
    "a_type": "two",
    "a_title": "Assignment 2",
    "symbol": 2,
    "show": false,
    "sub_a_title": "Assignment Information",
    "tooltip": {
        "left": 200
    },
    "buttonPos":{
        "left": 250
    },
    "printTop": 250,
    "instructions": "Instructions here",
    "due_date": "29.png",
    "percentage": "10.png",
    "taskA": {
      "a_title": "Assignment 2 info",
        "name": "Option A",
        "information": "Instructions for task A",
        "selectA": false
    },
    "taskB": {
      "a_title": "Assignment 2 info",
        "name": "Option B",
        "information": "Instructions for task B",
        "selectB": false
    }
}
]
```

**assignment.ts - here's the data types**

```
export class Assignment {
    a_type: string;
    a_title: string;
    symbol: any;
    show: boolean;
    tooltip: any;
    left: number;
    buttonPos:any;
    printTop: number;
    instructions: string;
    due_date: string;
    percentage: string;
    taskA: any;
    name: string;
    information: string;
    selectA: boolean;
    taskB: any;
    selectB: boolean;
  }
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's because the structure of the object literals don't match the `Assignment` structure.

Typescript is a *structurally typed* language, which means that a class' type and properties are defined by its structure. An object literal can be considered a type of a class if the structure maches. For example, say we have this class

```
class Person {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}
```

Instead of the normal way on instantiating a class with the `new` keyword,

```
let person: Person = new Person();
person.firstName = "Stack";
person.lastName = "Overflow";
```

we could use the following:

```
let person: Person = {
  firstName: "Stack",
  lastName: "Overflow"
}
```

If we didn't include the `lastName` property, we would get a compile error as the *structure* does not match that of the `Person` class and we tried to type it as a `Person`.

As far as your code, a few things I see wrong are:

1. You're missing `name` and `information` because they are nested in the `typeA`. This doesn't work as they need to be in the main structure, as that is what is defined in `Assignment`
2. You need `taskB` in the first object
3. You're missing `selectA` and `selectB` from the main structure of the objects.

There are probably more errors also, but hopefully you get the point

If you want to make things optional, you can use the `?` operator

```
interface Assignment {
  name?: string;
}
```

If you want nesting you can do that too

```
interface Assignment {
  taskA?: { name: string },
  taskB?: { name: string }
}
```

**See also:**

- [TypeScript docs on Type Compatibility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html)
- [TypeScript docs in Interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I fixed my data structures and now I dont get any more errors.

Answer (score 3):

The error is pretty clear:

> Property 'left' is missing ...

Your `Assignment` class declares a member named `left` but both of your json objects don't have it.
You have a few more properties you haven't set in your json objects, [here's a working version in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Assignment%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a_type%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a_title%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20symbol%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20show%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20tooltip%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20left%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20buttonPos%3Aany%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20printTop%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20instructions%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20due_date%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20percentage%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20taskA%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20information%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20selectA%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20taskB%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20selectB%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20const%20Assignments%3A%20Assignment%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22a_type%22%3A%20%22one%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22a_title%22%3A%20%22Assignment%201%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22symbol%22%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22show%22%3A%20false%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22left%22%3A%204%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22name%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22information%22%3A%20%22information%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22selectA%22%3A%20false%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22taskB%22%3A%20%22%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22selectB%22%3A%20false%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22tooltip%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22left%22%3A%2082%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22buttonPos%22%3A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22left%22%3A%20130%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22printTop%22%3A%200%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22instructions%22%3A%20%22Instructions%20here%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22due_date%22%3A%20%22sept-15.png%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22percentage%22%3A%20%2210.png%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22taskA%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Option%20A%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22a_title%22%3A%20%22Task%20A%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22information%22%3A%20%22Instructions%20for%20task%20A%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22selectA%22%3A%20true%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22a_type%22%3A%20%22two%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22a_title%22%3A%20%22Assignment%202%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22symbol%22%3A%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22show%22%3A%20false%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22left%22%3A%204%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22name%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22information%22%3A%20%22information%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22selectA%22%3A%20false%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22selectB%22%3A%20false%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22tooltip%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22left%22%3A%20200%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22buttonPos%22%3A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22left%22%3A%20250%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22printTop%22%3A%20250%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22instructions%22%3A%20%22Instructions%20here%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22due_date%22%3A%20%2229.png%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22percentage%22%3A%20%2210.png%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22taskA%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22a_title%22%3A%20%22Assignment%202%20info%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Option%20A%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22information%22%3A%20%22Instructions%20for%20task%20A%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22selectA%22%3A%20false%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22taskB%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22a_title%22%3A%20%22Assignment%202%20info%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Option%20B%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22information%22%3A%20%22Instructions%20for%20task%20B%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22selectB%22%3A%20false%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%5D).

You can declare the properties is optional if you want:

```
class Assignment {
    a_type?: string;
    ...
}
```

But even without the errors, you have a problem.
You're not creating instances of the class `Assignment`, you only create objects that match the class properties.
It works because typescript is using [duck typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#introduction), but if you'll have methods in the `Assignment` then your objects won't have those.
You can do this:

```
export const Assignments: Assignment[] = [new Assignment(), new Assignment()];

Object.assign(Assignments[0], FIRST_JSON_OBJ);
Object.assign(Assignments[1], SECOND_JSON_OBJ);
```

Or you can have a constructor in `Assignment` who receives this json object and intialize itself.

Comment: Thanks for the info and the demo. I see more of my mistakes.